# Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, null given

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-9

No command is working, I also tried to update Composer, but the case is the same. I found a guide that said to ignore the `url()` and `asset()` method, but it did not solve the issue.

> Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct(): Argument #2 ($request)
> must be of type Illumina   te\Http\Request, null given, called in
> D:\artyir\xampp8\htdocs\boilerplate\core\vendor\laravel\
> framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 65

Comment: this is probably a consequence of something else which is unclear here. This error happens when the request object is not bound which should only ever happen if the Kernel was not booted and hasn't invoked the router correctly. I'm afraid you have to do a rather deep dive in your code to investigate what might be happening

Comment: There must be a problem with your routes, review them. Btw you can clear cache routes to get a refresh on cache. running `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @ManuelGlez  any artisan command gives error in this case, so `route:clear`  will never work.

Comment: You're right @Astro

Comment: You may have a call to route(), url(), asset() or similar Laravel helper function in one of your /config/ files.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I got that error message because I used `url()` in config folder.
Try not to use any `url()` or `asset()` in the config folder mainly in app.php.

Comment: thanks, in my case was route() inside config that was causing the problem, so your comment made me realize that.

Comment: you can use storage_path() function instead.

Answer (score 12):

I faced same problem when I used asset() function in some file in config folder, so try to remove any helper function from all config files, it prevents the loading of the app routes.

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by changing this line:

```
asset('img/order_system/shopify.png')
```

to

```
'/img/order_system/shopify.png'
```

in config.

Answer (score 3):

This also happens when you use `route()` inside a Laravel config file.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this issue when I was using `url()` in one of my config files. What I did to fix it was this

```
PHP_SAPI === 'cli' ? false : url('')
```

PHP_SAPI returns the same values as php_sapi_name(). can read more at php docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php